# How do I change a picture while scrolling down a web page?

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a website where a picture is in a fixed position.
The picture should change when scrolling.
I have 6 pictures in my img folder, the first picture is implemented in my index file.
Now I want the picture changes 5 times
for example: I am scrolling down and at 20% PIC1 changes to PIC2.
And then at 40% changes PIC2 to PIC3 and so on.

I tried javascript but failed.

```
var onScrollHandler = function() {
  var newImageUrl = Pic1.svg;
  var scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;
  if (scrollTop > 100) {
     newImageUrl = "pic2.svg"
  }
  if (scrollTop > 200) {
     newImageUrl = "pic3.svg"
  }
  if (scrollTop > 300) {
     newImageUrl = "pic4.svg"
  }
  if (scrollTop > 400) {
     newImageUrl = "pic5.svg"
  }
  if (scrollTop > 500) {
     newImageUrl = "pic6.svg"
  }
  Pic1.svg = newImageUrl;
};
object.addEventListener ("scroll", onScrollHandler);
```

I hope it is understandable enough and someone can help me until tomorrow.
Have a nice day and thank you anyways!

Comment: Please include your code as well, better to put on JS fiddle if possible. That way people can understand and help you better

Comment: You can change what an image tag shows by changing the `.src` value of the element. Trigger this by listening for [scroll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/scroll_event) events

Comment: Please add your code snippet that you have tried.Then we can understand your real problem and help you even better way.

Comment: what is `Pic1`? what is it's `svg` property?

Comment: Scalable Vector Graphics=Svg
I am an art student and we work with svg files at the moment but could also be .jpg.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code that approximates your requirements. You'll probably need to test it properly before you use it in any production code, but hopefully, it'll point you in the right direction.

All the magic is in the javascript code.

```js
// The available scroll space in the browser window is evaluated and 
// assigned to h here
var h = Math.max(document.body.scrollHeight, document.body.offsetHeight, document.documentElement.clientHeight, document.documentElement.scrollHeight, document.documentElement.offsetHeight) - window.innerHeight;

// h is divided into 5 equals parts
var diff = h / 5;
var processing = false;

// variable to keep track of how far the user has scrolled so image can be changed
var diff_tracker = 0;

// variable to keep track of the current image being displayed
var current_image_index = 1;

var last_known_scroll_position = 0;


// this function changes the image displayed depending the scroll position 
function changeImage(scroll_pos) {
  if (scroll_pos === 1) {
    document.getElementById("image").src = "https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg";
  } else if (scroll_pos === 2) {
    document.getElementById("image").src = "https://www.w3schools.com/Html/img_girl.jpg";
  } else if (scroll_pos === 3) {
    document.getElementById("image").src = "https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_5terre_wide.jpg";
  } else if (scroll_pos === 4) {
    document.getElementById("image").src = "https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_snowtops.jpg";
  } else if (scroll_pos === 5) {
    document.getElementById("image").src = "https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_nature.jpg";
  }
}

// on scroll, this listener fires and updates the image being displayed as required
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  var scroll_position = window.scrollY;

  if (!processing) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
      if (last_known_scroll_position === 0) {
        last_known_scroll_position = scroll_position;
      } else {
        diff_tracker += scroll_position - last_known_scroll_position;
        if (diff_tracker >= 0) {
          while (diff_tracker >= diff) {
            diff_tracker -= diff;
            current_image_index++;
            changeImage(current_image_index);
          }
        } else {
          while (diff_tracker < -diff) {
            diff_tracker += diff;
            current_image_index--;
            changeImage(current_image_index);
          }
        }

      }

      last_known_scroll_position = scroll_position;
      processing = false;
    });

    processing = true;
  }
});

function recalculate() {
    h = Math.max( document.body.scrollHeight, document.body.offsetHeight, document.documentElement.clientHeight, document.documentElement.scrollHeight, document.documentElement.offsetHeight) - window.innerHeight;
    diff = h / 5;
}

// if the window is resized, the scrolling height and diff variable are recalculated
window.onresize = recalculate;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    div.sticky {
      position: -webkit-sticky;
      position: sticky;
      top: 0;
      padding: 70px;
      font-size: 20px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <h2>Scroll Down to See the Effect</h2>
  <div class="sticky"><img id="image" width=300 height=300 src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg" /> </div>


  <h2>Some random text to enable scroll..</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus
    vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Mauris ante ligula, facilisis sed ornare eu, lobortis in odio. Praesent convallis urna a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue
    ut aliquet. Mauris ante ligula, facilisis sed ornare eu, lobortis in odio. Praesent convallis urna a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet
    sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fst hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis.
    Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta. Cras ac leo purus. Mauris quis diam velit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet,
    nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Mauris ante ligula, facilisis sed ornare eu,
    lobortis in odio. Praesent convallis urna a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis.</p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Unfortunately I always get an error: The property "scrollHeight" of an undefined or null reference can not be retrieved.

Comment: You get the error when you run the snippet here? Or on your own implementation

Comment: I have it and it works.
Could you still tell me how to add a link to the last picture for example: I press on the last picture and I come on google.

Comment: Just wrap the `img` tag with an `a` tag. Like `<a href="https://google.com/"><img id="image" width=300 height=300 src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg" /> </a>`.

Comment: If you only want the redirect to happen on the last image, just set the `href` attribute to `#` whenever the image is changed to any image that isn't the last one. When it gets changed to the last one, set the `href` to your preferred url.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `src` of your image tag in javascript when certain amount of screen is scrolled.
Try running this example by expanding the snippet in full screen

```js
function change() {
  var percent = (document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop) /
    ((document.documentElement.scrollHeight || document.body.scrollHeight) -
      document.documentElement.clientHeight) * 100;
  var image = document.getElementById("img");
  if (percent < 20) {
    image.src = "https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_mountains.jpg";
  } else if (percent < 40) {
    image.src = "https://www.w3schools.com/Html/img_girl.jpg";
  } else if (percent < 60) {
    image.src = "https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_5terre_wide.jpg";
  } else if (percent < 80) {
    image.src = "https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_snowtops.jpg";
  } else if (percent < 90) {
    image.src = "https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_nature.jpg";
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 32px;
}

#left {
  float: left;
  width: 60%;
}

#stick {
  position: fixed;
  left: 60%;
  float: right;
  width: 35%;
}
```

```html
<body onscroll="change()">
  <div id="left">
    <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt, esse laborum omnis nisi quo enim corrupti dolorum dicta, tenetur error perferendis perspiciatis dolor nulla, consequuntur numquam totam commodi aliquam consequatur rem quos? Quam vel,
      veniam deleniti maiores sapiente aliquid perferendis distinctio ut earum libero ipsum consectetur sint ex esse voluptate maxime molestias doloribus. Obcaecati quo non animi quas expedita. Doloribus aliquam eos ut perferendis inventore et ratione
      nostrum fugiat dolore libero! Eveniet quam quidem natus placeat veniam sint, nihil aut tenetur repellat pariatur, sunt eos soluta, neque explicabo ipsam corrupti nisi. Magnam facilis neque tempora ducimus doloribus explicabo minima natus.
    </p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae soluta esse, voluptatem ad dolorem nisi, voluptatibus error repudiandae similique tempora adipisci sint doloremque iusto amet laudantium atque, animi eaque impedit corrupti nesciunt blanditiis
      dolorum quo. Quae aperiam autem excepturi commodi, accusantium sed tempora inventore, dolore, at ut eligendi culpa beatae vel. Cumque impedit quod earum commodi doloremque optio culpa ea veritatis sed delectus fugiat nemo, corporis dolore officiis
      quaerat unde reiciendis, debitis ratione ipsa obcaecati voluptates. Ducimus doloremque id quis accusamus enim, eligendi accusantium nam inventore itaque deleniti quidem error aut? Ea ipsum velit aliquid commodi voluptas distinctio officiis, similique
      facere ratione dolores corporis, architecto dolore ab amet quia expedita hic quam! Blanditiis suscipit fugiat esse nemo, modi facere nesciunt!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Ipsa rerum ex consequuntur enim repellendus repellat, ratione eveniet illo libero voluptate vel, reprehenderit voluptas quis obcaecati aliquam inventore! Provident alias quos praesentium consequatur
      doloribus nemo rerum quod autem totam, suscipit molestiae repellendus perferendis placeat sapiente vero tempora aliquam nihil quae? Praesentium minima perferendis voluptatibus laboriosam natus molestiae, maxime aperiam, voluptatem adipisci aliquid
      itaque id. Incidunt assumenda, consectetur odio temporibus doloribus eaque illo fugit deserunt, eos repudiandae expedita porro iste, facilis quaerat iure blanditiis iusto sapiente?</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos quod dolorum maiores dignissimos minima! Obcaecati, perspiciatis natus. Tempore obcaecati esse ad veniam earum alias, illum voluptate et illo sit eum repellat dolorum fugit at, totam architecto
      id eaque corrupti.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Explicabo atque, non eius repellat voluptate id suscipit. Quod at facere consequuntur possimus, impedit doloremque dolorem accusamus recusandae veniam ipsum eum cumque. Quas in repudiandae tenetur
      harum porro. Maxime iure dolor, repudiandae deleniti quidem ipsum ipsam animi sequi non amet repellat deserunt. Provident labore eveniet nulla aliquid vero consequatur quis quasi quas? Esse rerum perferendis cupiditate, voluptates voluptatibus magnam
      facilis quisquam molestias delectus, sequi officia dolor iusto nostrum repudiandae laboriosam?
    </p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut perspiciatis dolor nesciunt et beatae vel architecto, officiis reiciendis assumenda sapiente laboriosam in, tenetur corrupti quam perferendis minus hic? Dolorum totam fuga accusamus corrupti?
      Quo inventore maiores dolorem impedit tempora veniam, totam asperiores eius architecto voluptatem dolor temporibus ratione rerum. Facilis nemo recusandae optio unde amet, ipsam harum delectus, alias aliquam, ipsa sed fugiat illo numquam repellendus
      aperiam?
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="stick">
    <h1>Fixed Image</h1>
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_mountains.jpg" id="img" width="100%" height="100%">
  </div>

</body>
```